# calling executable from matlab function, crash handling

Tags: matlab, crash

I have an executable `oo.exe`, which takes input as `1` or `2`, so in command prompt, I can write

```
oo 1
oo 2
```

I also do redirection to print output to a text file.

I am doing same thing using `system` command from MATLAB.

```
system('oo 1 >> op.txt');
system('oo 1 >> op.txt');
```

Everything works fine except when the .exe crashes. When the *.exe crashes for say first line, I expect that the text will get printed till the crash point in `op.txt` and the second line (argument `2`) will execute normally (assuming no crash for argument `2`).
However this does not happen, Even when second line executes normally, nothing gets printed.

However if I do same from command prompt in two consecutive commands, everything works fine. I tried tricking by writing a batch file **test.bat** and calling it from MATLAB using `system`, but of no avail.
Indeed when I ran this bat file from command prompt, on second execution, a message came that the file `op.txt` is locked.

Just to tell you, all this happens only when there is crash.

does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: I tried calling test.bat directly from window command prompt, I got the same problem. Though I could not solve the problem, it seems the problem is related to buffer, which gets corrupted some how, or when the program exits due to crash, it clears buffer irrespective of whether the buffer is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

Put a try catch around the system call. It seems like it might be throwing an error, which causes the script to crash.

```
try
system('oo 1 >> op.txt');
catch
end

try
system('oo 2 >> op.txt');
catch
end
```